# Does Adell (DLC) gain Big Bang in Disgaea 4?

Tags: disgaea-4

The title pretty much says it all.  Does Adell naturally (without needing to go to Chara World) gain the Big Bang skill, and if so, at what level?  I've tried searching for it, and no one seems to have a skill/level table for DLC characters, at least that I can find.

Comment: I doubt it. I've never seen a story character get a level 5/6 weapon skill naturally. I bet you'll have to Character World it. And FWIW he didn't learn it in D3 either, but I don't have him in D4

Comment: @Ben: you sure?  It's been a while since I played 3, but IIRC he did get it there...

Comment: He *can* get it, but I'm pretty sure you have to do it via Character world. I could boot it up and check later though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since no one seemed to know, I tested it and found out that yes, he does gain the skill at level 500.